# adding new row to datagrid view programmatically

Tags: c#

I Have a datagridview that gets data from database and shows to the user,I also have three textboxes through which user can enter the value into the datagrid view if I select an already existing row in the datgrid and then enter value by text boxes it makes the changes and when I push change button changes are made successfully in both db and the datagridview
but if I select an empty row in the datagrid view and try to enter the values I cannot new row is not added to the datagrid view although allow user to add new row is set to true.

```
 private void txtName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
    {
        dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Name"].Value = txtName.Text;
    }
}

private void txtRelation_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
    {
        dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Relation"].Value = txtRelation.Text;
    }
}
private void txtID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
    {
        dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ID"].Value = txtID.Text;
    }

}
```

Comment: How is your DataGridView bound?

Comment: @DavidB sorry I am totally new to this and I am making modifications to an existing code what does it mean? my DataGridView gets data from existing database

Comment: @DavidB it is bound to datatable

Answer (score 0):

Check if your gridview is **readonly**. If **Readonly** is true then set it to false to enable user add new row. Another reason might be the "**EditMode**" property of DataGridView. It should not be "**Edit Programatically**" if you want to allow user to add new row

Comment: readonly is false edit mode is edit on key stroke or f2 and allow user to add new row is set to true

Answer (score 0):

You have to **double click** a row to actually create a new row. However, if you do not want the stress of double clicking, you could make the row select event to *perform a click* on the row.